# Dynamically add array textbox in a form

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, dynamic, textbox

I need to add in all the textbox manually in my project.

```
<form>
<?php for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){ ?>
<input type="text" name="product[]">
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

how can i solve this problem so that the number of product for insert can be flexible.
For example, user1 need to purchase 4 item, user2 wan to purchase 8 item. wihtout dynamic textbox, i need to add the textbox manually by adjusting the looping value (in my coding).

Comment: And what is your problem here..?

Comment: Where should the number of product input fields come from?

Comment: Can you please explain more about your requirement? (I need to add in all the textbox manually in my project???)

Comment: It depends on your table make id field auto increment ?!

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want the number to be flexible?

Comment: when i need key in the information of the product.i need to count the total and adjust the looping (in my coding).I hope i can make it dynamic so that i can add the textbox without modifying my coding.

Comment: why i need to put all the product in a single form because i want to update all together with a single submit button.

Comment: Well then count all your products and then set the counted value instead of "3" in your for-loop. If you hav an array with all your products in it (guessing) you can count them with `count($myArray)`

Comment: this interface is for customer, therefore the number of product will change accordingly. lets say, customer1 want to purchase 4 product and customer2 want to purchase 10 product, what should i do to fix this problem ?

Comment: If customer select how much product he want to purchase on diferent page, then simply push that value in session and get it on this page then you will have count of products for current customer the you can pass that variable value instead of 3.

Comment: is it means every time i need to count the product manually before i key in ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this is an update to customer products right?
if so, you probably have products array somewhere.

so you might do :

```
$products = $customer->products ;//or your array
for($i=0;$i<count($products);$i++){
// your code
}
```

**or** you can add it via javascript (sounds more like it if this is the purchase moment - new products, not update)

**or** you might want to have somewhere a config per customer.

**or Please be more specific and more descriptive**

Comment: is something like cash bill,i need to prepare textbox to allow staff to enter product information.And different customer may purchase different amount of product, therefore i need a dynamic textbox function to ensure that i can add in more textbox anytime to key in the product information

Comment: ya, as your first condition, this is a purchase moment, is new product, not update.